# hoisting issue using THREEjs loading textures

Tags: javascript

My issue is within this code (I'll explain the best I can):

This snippet of code is within a for loop.
I load a list of image files from a csv file and parse using lineBreak.
I use this technique to make it easy to update images to my website.
This all works fine, but I want to preserve the aspect ratio of of each image. so the code below is use to check the width and height of each image and using a fixed width set the new height of each plane geometry as I load the texture.

```
texture[i] = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(lineBreak[i],function(tex){
  thumbHeight = Math.ceil( (tex.image.height / tex.image.width) * thumbWidth); //here I calculate the new image/texture/thumbnail height
picH = thumbHeight; }); //both picH and thumbHeight are declared as global variables
```

// this line of code below is the issue. It gets hoisted above the previous function and thumbHeight is initialized as undefined. If I put it within the function it produces nothing(no errors). Using console.log within the function show all the correct results, but outside the function the thumbHeight is undefined.

mesh = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);

you may have guessed that I am new to Javascript and threejs and you'd be right. I'm trying to recreate my website which I created in Flash actionscript many years back.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Ok I figured it out.

Comment: I needed to create the Plane geometry before my for loop and within my texture function do some more math and then scale the mesh. Listed below:

Comment: texture[i] = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(lineBreak[i],function(tex){
      thumbHeight = Math.ceil( (tex.image.height/ tex.image.width) * thumbWidth);
      if(thumbHeight > th){
        th = thumbHeight;
      }
    picH = thumbHeight;
    let sha = picH/thumbWidth; // turn height pixels to a number that scale can use 
    thumb[i].scale.set(1,sha); //scale the mesh
    });

Comment: How do I mark my question as "Solved"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

I needed to create the Plane geometry before my for loop and within my texture function do some more math and then scale the mesh. Listed below:

```
texture[i] = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(lineBreak[i], function(tex){ 
     thumbHeight = Math.ceil( (tex.image.height/ tex.image.width) * thumbWidth);
     if(thumbHeight > th){ th = thumbHeight; } picH = thumbHeight;
     let sha = picH/thumbWidth; // turn height pixels to a number that scale can use
     thumb[i].scale.set(1,sha); //scale the mesh 
});
```